# How to prevent duplicate value generation within two transactions

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, race-condition

I have a Spring Boot application which gets requests via a REST API.

After receiving such a request I generate an offerID for my object. this is not the primary key of the database, it is just a human readable number we communicate to our customers instead of the normal database id.

this offer id looks something like "16051801" for the first request we received on the 18th of May 2016.

This is stored as a String in the database to select the current "max" with something like `SELECT count(r) FROM Request as r WHERE r.offerId LIKE ?1%`
and I just put in the current date "160518" and get the number of requests stored there and just take the count + 1 as the next value.

As you might already guess, this brings some problems.

On the one side this works fine, as we do not have that much traffic right now on this site.

But, if we have two requests which are coming in in nearly the same moment I get something like a "race condition" and I create the same offerId twice, which is not that cool.

I have already added a unique constraint to this column, which prevents the creation of multiple entries with the same value, but in that case, one of the two requests is failing.

I already tried something like that:

```
try {
     super.create(customerRequest);
} catch (DataIntegrityViolationException ex) {
     if (ex.getCause() instanceof ConstraintViolationException) {
         ConstraintViolationException constraintViolationException = (ConstraintViolationException) ex.getCause();
         if (constraintViolationException.getCause().getMessage().contains("'UC_CUSTOMERREQUESTOFFERNUMBER_COL'")){
             customerRequest.setOfferNumber(generateOfferNumber(customerRequest));
                 super.create(customerRequest);
        }
    }
}
```

But in that case I always get something like a `Do not flush the session if an Exception occurs`

basically In that case I am able to handle and solve the problem, but Spring / Hibernate prevents me from doing this.

So the real question is, what is the best practise to handle such a "problem" in a way which is not hacky (I also tried stuff with Thread.sleep(), which felt not really good....) and also scalable (should also work in the future with multiple instances of the application).

As a database we use MySQL, so as far as I know we can't move this "ID-Generation" into the database.

Comment: how do you generate the string?

Comment: Create a separate table to maintain the daily counters. You can use a modified `MySQLMaxValueIncrementer` to enable the functionality. You can update a record for each day and get the last updated value with `last_insert_id`. Take a look at the `MySQLMaxValueIncrementer` for inspiration.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL inherently does not have the concept of a sequence. 
The closest thing you have is the AUTO_INCREMENT.

For MyISAM tables, there is an easy way that you need. Just save the Date of the order in the table and depending on the date, the auto_increment happens.

This is what the MYSQL manual says:

"For MyISAM tables, you can specify AUTO_INCREMENT on a secondary column in a multiple-column index. In this case, the generated value for the AUTO_INCREMENT column is calculated as MAX(auto_increment_column) + 1 WHERE prefix=given-prefix. This is useful when you want to put data into ordered groups"

Check this link for more information.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html

Answer (score 1):

For your last thought about moving ID generation logic to DB, Yes you can do it.
You can create a sequence for the non-pk column. You can have the logic there in the sequence which will automatically invoked using hibernate when any inserts occurred.

MySQL and Hibernate both can resolve your problem by using the concept of Sequence.

We had a scenario, where we had to generate a custom key with the format like "PK-ABCD-001" such as "545455-ABCD-008". Using sequence we have resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just throw out several ideas:

1. In Oracle, we have "SEQUENCE" that gives you a new number every time you query from it.  There is no direct replacement in MySql though but it should be possible to simulate the effect by using a dummy table with an auto-increment column
2. I have once written a little stored proc to perform sequence number generation (which takes care of date-prefix, and auto-reset of sequence every day etc).  Autonomous transaction is used to avoid concurrent transactions blocking each other.  There is no direct replacement (again) for autonomous transaction in MySQL but there are some tricks to achieve similar result.
3. Write a little network service that perform the "sequence generation", and expose it by whatever way you want (SOAP, REST etc).  Given the simplicity of the logic, I don't think you need it to be that scalable.  Store the current sequence in DB (so that it is recoverable), and have the sequence generation logic having its own short transaction.  You may improve performance by, for example, "caching" the sequence numbers (e.g. increment the number in DB by 100 every time, and you can return 100 sequence numbers without accessing the DB.)

Comment: In new oracle we have "IDENTITY" (https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/identity-columns-in-oracle-12cr1) , Adam, you should switch to IDENTITY

Comment: I believe IDENTITY is not solving the problem I am trying to solve with Oracle Sequence.

Comment: IDENTITY is indeed a Oracle Sequence as an Pseudocolumn.

Comment: But it is still not trying to solve what I was trying to solve. OP is asking for a way in MySql to generate a running sequence value for a non-PK (hence non-auto-increment) column.

Comment: You are right, its only a comment from professional to professional :D

Answer (score 1):

in order to make the id generation process atomic, you could save an AtomicInteger field for the suffix,  in your application context if you have only one centralized server. This field would be initialized at each start of day to be 0 and every time a new transaction comes you use the method: `increamentAndGet ()`

If you are using multiple servers in a distributed environment (cloud) I suggest you look for a way to store it on one of the servers and approach it directly from all others. Amazon's AWS for example, has a service called Redis which provides a cache-mem server that can store ids like that and get and increament them atomically.

Answer (score 1):

What Isolation level are you using for the Transaction. You need to use the "SERIALIZABLE" Transaction Isolation, for this scenario.
Try the following on your transaction.

```
@Transactional(isolation=Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
```